# Как удалять стикеры тг ботом?

Tags: python, aiogram

Обычные сообщения и смайлы можно удалить через `delete_message`, а вот стикеры и GIF не подпадают под это.
Как собственно удалять эти стикеры и гифы?

Comment: Что-то мне кажется вы их просто неправильно ловите

Comment: Я просто через print(message) вывожу все в консоль, и от стикеров ничего не приходит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=types.ContentTypes.STICKER)
async def bot_message(message: types.Message):
    await message.delete()
```